# Do other Houses have a theme song like "The Rains of Castamere" for House Lannister?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

We know that "The Rains of Castamere" is identified as "The Lannisters Song".

Do other Houses (e.g. House Stark, House Targaryen, etc) in *A Song of Ice and Fire* and *Game of Thrones* have a song that is identified with them?

Comment: It's worth keeping in mind that this particular song has a *very* specific history with House Lannister. Indeed, it's relatively recent history as it refers to the deeds of Tywin Lannister. It's basically propaganda for his regime and the resurgence of the Lannisters after years of decline.  So it's not exactly a long held tradition and one shouldn't expect to find equivalent songs of other houses. There probably are songs sung by the men and banners of other houses, but they're more likely to be specific to the culture of the region, not necessarily the ruling house itself.

Comment: House Mormont and *The bear and the maiden fair* :-P

Comment: I add ASOIAF tag as you mention it in the question

Comment: Robb Stark was known to jam out to Duran Duran's "Hungry Like the Wolf"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Kris says, "The Rains of Castamere" is not an official song as their sigil or motto is official. There is no official anthem/songs related to any House. Still, we can do a list of songs more or less related to a house or a character:

- [Battle of the Blackwater](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_of_the_Blackwater_(song)): song about the events of the Battle of the Blackwater, and describes the valor of King Joffrey I Baratheon and Queen Regent Cersei Lannister
- [Brave Danny Flint](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Brave_Danny_Flint): song about Danny Flint, a girl who disguised herself as a boy to join the Night's Watch but ended up raped and murdered by the black brothers.
- [The hammer and the anvil](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/The_hammer_and_the_anvil): song about the strategy used by Prince Baelor Targaryen and Prince Maekar Targaryen during the Battle of the Redgrass Field.
- [Lord Harte Rode Out on a Rainy Day"](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lord_Harte_Rode_Out_on_a_Rainy_Day): song about Lord Harte
- [Lord Renly's Ride](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Lord_Renly%27s_Ride): a song that narrate how Renly's ghost repents from his attempt to usurp his nephew, returns to this world to defend the realm from Stannis Baratheon and then goes to Highgarden to see his true love's face one last time
- [The Night That Ended](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/The_Night_That_Ended): not exactly related to a House, but related to the Night's Watch that rides to meet the Others in the Battle for the Dawn.
- [The Rains of Castamere](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/The_Rains_of_Castamere): The most famous song in the list, a song which immortalizes the destruction of House Reyne of Castamere by Tywin Lannister.
- [A Thousand Eyes, and One](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Thousand_Eyes,_and_One): song about one of the Great Bastards, Brynden Rivers.
- [When Willum's Wife Was Wet](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/When_Willum%27s_Wife_Was_Wet): song, ostensibly about rain. It may be a reference to House Willum.
- [Wolf in the Night](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Wolf_in_the_Night): song about the Battle of Oxcross, a decisive victory of Stark/Tully over Lannister